# Remove Application from Mountain Lion's Twitter Apps

Tags: macos, security, osx-mountain-lion, twitter

How can I remove an application completely from the list under "`Security & Privacy`" -> "`Privacy`" -> "`Twitter`"?

Comment: Which Twitter clients integrate with ML at that level? I tried the official one and Tweetdeck, both seem to do their own authentication.

Comment: It's more for following through Mountain Lion and such. Clear, the to-do list is one example (it asks for permission when you follow the creators).

Answer (score 0):

If the Twitter apps section behaves similar to that of Contacts, it will show *all installed applications* that "have requested access to Twitter", and allows you to *disable access* for specific apps.

Delete them from your system to completely remove them from the list.